# Call to undefined function set_flashdata() in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, controller

I have tried to use `set_flashdata()` inside my controller as

`$this->session->set_flashdata('para',$project_id);`

but I am getting error

> Call to undefined function set_flashdata()

I have already added session inside autoload file like

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'Pagination','form_validation');
```

please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Edit your question with the controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your syntax is incorrect

`$this->session->set_flashdata('para',$project_id);`

not

`$this->session>set_flashdata('para',$project_id);`

Comment: he loaded session library on autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

In here `$this->session>set_flashdata('para',$project_id);`

> > session **->**  is missing